# Laravel backend doesn't send data to Vuejs frontend. how I resolve this?

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, frontend, backend

I used vuejs frontend and Laravel backend for my application. It perfectly worked on Localhost. but when I deployed in shared hosting, it says this error on the browser console log

```
vue-resource.esm.js:996 GET http://regback.dazkon.com/api/getStudent 500 (Internal Server Error)
/student:1 Uncaught (in promise) 
e {url: 'http://regback.dazkon.com/api/getStudent', ok: false, status: 500, statusText: 'Internal Server Error', headers: e, …}


body: {message: 'Class "PDO" not found', exception: 'Error', file: '/home2/dazkonco/regback.dazkon.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php', line: 1431, trace: Array(51)}
bodyText: "{\n    \"message\": \"Class \\\"PDO\\\" not found
headers: e {map: {…}}
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
url: "http://regback.dazkon.com/api/getStudent"
data: (...)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Did you run composer install on your server and do you have the appropriate DB services installed?

Comment: What does `php -m` show?

Comment: @IGP [PHP Modules]
bcmath       
bz2
calendar     
Core
ctype        
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo     
filter       
ftp
gettext      
hash
iconv        
json
libxml       
mbstring     
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]